# Show/hide div on checkbox click with unknown amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an auto-generated list of sections that looks like that:

```
<div class="list">
    <section class="visible list-0"></section>
    <section class="hidden list-1"></section>
    <section class="hidden list-2"></section>
    <section class="hidden list-3"></section>
    <!-- unknown amount of sections -->
</div>
```

And a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="accept" value="1" required>
```

If checkbox is checked I want to hide the first section `.list-0` and show next section `list-1`. Then if checkbox is checked again, hide `list-0` and `list-1` and show `list-2`. Please note that the amount of sections in unknown and can be up to about 25.

The following code is what I wrote by now.

```
$('#accept').on('click',function() {
  var count_sections = $('.list > section').length;

  $('.list-0').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
  $('.list-1').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');

  // this should uncheck the checkbox
  $('#accept').attr('checked', false);
});
```

I want to automate it so it will work no matter how many sections I have. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have only one checkbox for all divs? So what happens when it is unchecked?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a checkbox for this and not a `<input type='button'>`?

Comment: Yes only one checkbox (dunno why). And there is a reason because the label says "Agree?"

Comment: what happens when unchecked ? and what happens every recheck ?

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
$('#accept').on('click',function() {
  $('.visible').next('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
  $('.visible:first').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');

  // this should uncheck the checkbox
  $('#accept').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: This will make the next div visible then hide them both

Comment: This doesn't work, as it hides them all with the line $('.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');

Answer (score 1):

this is my first approach. you select the visible element, hide it, toggle class visible, select the next element, show it and toggle class visible.
i completely removed the hidden class from this solution, since we switch between two states - visible and hidden - we only need the visible class to know if it is visible or hidden...

```
$('#accept').on('click',function() {
    if (!$("section:last").hasClass("visible")) 
    {
        $('.visible').hide().toggleClass("visible").next()
          .show().toggleClass("visible");

        // this should uncheck the checkbox
        $('#accept').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

UPDATED FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/tbu116w8/2/
added the if statement to check, if you are currently on the last section

Comment: When I reach the last section I want allow user to check the same checkbox and do nothing.

Comment: haven't updated the fiddle, but the code snippet. just add the if statement, to stop at the last section. i'll provide additional snippets in a minute...

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because my php generated code have classes `visible` and `hidden` and your code uses hide() and show(). After first section it does not show anything.

Comment: then adapt! it is really easy! http://jsfiddle.net/tbu116w8/4/ took me about 1 minute! i use hide and show, because i havent included any css in my fiddle to define the .hidden and .visible classes display style! so if you just use the toggleClass function with both classes and remove hide and show, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current visible in a variable. Then show the next one and hide the current one. This is more efficient than finding the visible one again.
You can also store the section you are showing next so you know when you have reached the end:

```js
    $('#accept').on('click',function() {
      var vis = $('.visible');
      var hid = vis.next('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
    
      $('#accept').prop('checked', false);

      // if we showed something (not at the end yet), hide the current visible one
      if(hid.length > 0) {
          vis.removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
      }
    });
```

```css
.visible {
    display:block;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
    <section class="visible list-0">0</section>
    <section class="hidden list-1">1</section>
    <section class="hidden list-2">2</section>
    <section class="hidden list-3">3</section>
    <!-- unknown amount of sections -->
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="accept" value="1" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var $previousSection=$(".list-0").show();
$('#accept').on('change',function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $previousSection.hide();
        $previousSection = $previousSection.next("section").show();    
    }  
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24nz847n/1/)

Answer (score -1):

use count on checkbox value
here is the working fiddle with the condition of upto 25

```
$('#accept').on('click',function() {
var count_sections = $('.list > section').length;
var count = $(this).val();
if(count > 25)
{
return false;
}
$('.list-'+count).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
count++;  
$('.list-'+count).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
$(this).val(count);
// this should uncheck the checkbox
$('#accept').attr('checked', false);
});
```

here is the html

```
<div class="list">
<section class="visible list-0">1st</section>
<section class="hidden list-1">2nd</section>
<section class="hidden list-2">3rd</section>
<section class="hidden list-3">4th</section>
<!-- unknown amount of sections -->
</div>
```

working example

```
jsfiddle.net/dr8Ln350/
```

Comment: Do not just post fiddle links as code - post the code!